# Javascript change text of all inputs

Tags: javascript, html, input, replace, getelementsbytagname

I'm really newbie at Web Development and I'm trying to change the text of some inputs, with Javascript. Here is a example of what my code have to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace "R$" with "" in the field below:</p>

<input id="demo" value="R$ 1223,43"></input>
<input id="demo1" value="R$ 134523,67"></input>
<input id="demo2" value="R$ 12453,41"></input>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementByTagName("input")

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

  var str=x[i].innerHTML; 

  var n=str.replace(",",".");
  var n1 = n.replace("R$ ","");

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n1;
 }


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I want to withdraw the "R$" and replace "," to "." for some math operations. And I have to do this with all inputs in my code.

Comment: .value, not .innerHTML - also I strongly recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) over http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the needed steps - at least step 1 through 3

1. moved the script to the head where it belongs
2. changed getElementByTagName to getElementsByTagName, plural
3. get and change x[i].value
4. chained the replace

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/v55kV/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Replace example</title>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input"); // plural

  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var str=x[i].value; 
    x[i].value=str.replace(",",".").replace("R$ ","");
  }
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Click the button to replace "R$" with "" in the field below:</p>

<input id="demo" value="R$ 1223,43"></input>
<input id="demo1" value="R$ 134523,67"></input>
<input id="demo2" value="R$ 12453,41"></input>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there, replacing a few things to make it look similar to this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); // ; was missing and you used getElementByTagName instead of getElementsByTagName

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        var str = x[i].value; // use .value

        var n = str.replace(",", ".");
        var n1 = n.replace("R$ ", "");

        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n1; // use x[i] again instead
        x[i].value = n1; // and again use .value
    }
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KUxBA/) - Running updated code

---

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use .value instead of .innerHTML. .innerHTML referes to text within the opening and closing of the tag.

Secondly, correct the spellings at var x=document.getElementByTagName("input")
it should be getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0):

this function should do what you want:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var eles=document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) 
    {
        if(eles[i].type != 'text') continue; // inputs that aren't of type text dont make sense here
        var str = eles[i].value; 
        str=str.replace(",",".");
        str=str.replace("R$ ","");
        eles[i].value=str;
    }
}
```